# Hadoop doesn't start Datanode on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop

I've installed Hadoop 2.6.0 in single-node mode on Ubuntu 15.10 VM.
When I start Hadoop with the command `./start-all.sh` all it works but when i launch Jps command I view

> 31602 NameNode 32453 Jps 32169 NodeManager 32045 ResourceManager

and Datanode hasn't be started.

I note also this warning:
"`16/01/15 11:18:54 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable`"

I report following log file

This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh

> Starting namenodes on [localhost] localhost: starting namenode,
>   logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-ale-namenode-ale-hadoop.out
>   localhost: starting datanode, logging to
>   /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-ale-datanode-ale-hadoop.out Starting
>   secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
>   0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-ale-secondarynamenode-ale-hadoop.out
>   starting yarn daemons starting resourcemanager, logging to
>   /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-ale-resourcemanager-ale-hadoop.out
>   localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to
>   /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-ale-nodemanager-ale-hadoop.out

What is the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: have to tried reformatting namenode and restart all service again?

Comment: yes! I've tried to reformatting more times but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, start-all.sh has indeed been deprecated. Instead you must use start-dfs.sh. Also you must not format name node more than once else all the data will go away. You may ignore the above warning and let it use built-in java classes.